# Webcam not working - works on Windows

Tags: 20.04, webcam, cheese, lsusb

My webcam is not working. On Windows 10 it works fine, no problems. `lsusb` shows no webcam. Cheese says there is an error.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am new to Ubuntu so my webcam has never worked, as far as I know.

EDIT: This is a laptop, model ThinkPad X1 Tablet G2. It is an integrated webcam.

**Output of ls -lah /dev/video***:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  0 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  1 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 14 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 15 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 16 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video12
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 17 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video13
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  2 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  3 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  8 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video4
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  9 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video5
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 10 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video6
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 11 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video7
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 12 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video8
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 13 nov.   1 21:00 /dev/video9
```

**Output of `lsusb`:**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:60a3 Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Tablet Thin Keyboard Gen 2
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the model of the webcam. Also, and I realize this may seem silly... is the webcam plugged in all the way? Also, [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -lah /dev/video*`

Comment: Thanks for including the webcam model! Can you also include the output of typing `ls -lah /dev/video*` into a terminal and pressing enter? Thanks! This will make it easier for us to solve your issue

Comment: @cocomac done! Sorry for the lack of information!

Comment: What error does cheese show? Also, have you tried guvcview?

Comment: @mchid guvcview says "no video device found" - but says I have video drivers installed... but none of the ones seem to work. https://imgur.com/a/ycgdmFq

Answer (score 1):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, since `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/video0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: `device="/dev/video"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)` what do you mean with this? I write it in the terminal and I get that `stat: cannot stat '/dev/video': No such file or directory`. This is probably just a beginner error, got no idea what that means.

Comment: Sorry, typo, fixed Use `device="/dev/video0"`.  Read `man adduser stat sudo bash`.

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. I added myself to the group "video" like you said... but camera still doesn't work. Even after a restart.